# sum array result numbers

Tags: php, arrays, count, sum

```
<?php
$text = $_POST['oviliz'];
$replaces = array(
    'a' => '1',
    'b' => '2',
    'c' => '3',
    'd' => '4',
    'e' => '5',
);
for( $i=0,$l=strlen($text);$i<$l;$i++ ){
    if( isset($replaces[$text[$i]]) ){
        $text[$i] = $replaces[$text[$i]];
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<p>My input text: <input name="oviliz" type="text"/><input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
</form>
<?php
echo "Numbers: ".$text;
$sum = 0;
$sum += array_sum(str_split($text));
echo "= " .$sum;
?>
```

I want to sum the replaced result. In my example if I type "abc" the result would be "123". I would like then to sum "1+2+3" and obtain the result which is 6.

**EDIT**
Thanks to Rizier123 I've changed `$sum += $text;` with `$sum += array_sum(str_split($text));`

I'm looking now how to print this only on request after the first replace result.

Comment: `$sum += array_sum(str_split($text));` ?!

Comment: This is working well, thank you Rizier123 . How I should do to print the sum only on request?

Comment: Just check if the submit button is pressed. (Should I convert it into a answer?)

Comment: Sure Rizier123. I will try to play with the submit in order to print it later, thanks.

Comment: posted it (included also the check if the submit button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the sum of your input just use this:

```
$sum += array_sum(str_split($text));
```

And to print it only when the submit button is pressed, just do a basic check like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>My input text: <input name="oviliz" type="text"/><input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
</form>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
     //^^^^^ Check's if the submit button is pressed                

        $text = $_POST['oviliz'];
        $replaces = array(
            'a' => '1',
            'b' => '2',
            'c' => '3',
            'd' => '4',
            'e' => '5',
        );

        for( $i=0,$l=strlen($text);$i<$l;$i++ ){
            if( isset($replaces[$text[$i]]) ){
                $text[$i] = $replaces[$text[$i]];
            }
        }


        echo "Numbers: ".$text;
        $sum = 0;
        $sum += array_sum(str_split($text));
        echo "= " .$sum;

    }

?>
```

Comment: That's great!
But I wasn't clear with the last question. In most of the cases the printed numbers is enough. Only sometimes I would like to request the total of those numbers. So I will need something like "click to see the total".

Comment: @OviLiz You could add a Checkbox with *show sum* or otherwise you have to do this with JS

Comment: Your original reply was "... with AJAX" :)
Actually switching everything to AJAX would avoid to refresh the page after each submit and I can commit my last request as well.

Comment: @OviLiz Yes AJAX would make it very easy (Ajax is kinda js, since ajax already means: asynchronous javascript and xml )

Comment: would you be able please to vote up my question as it seems it prohibits me from answering a question? :(

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of completing your homework:

```
$sum = array_sum(
    array_intersect_key($replaces, array_flip(str_split($_POST['oviliz'])))
);
```

Comment: By _"Doesn't do anything"_, do you mean it returns 6? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/948a1a468bdb27e85f3164ba70a576c47e3756ed

Comment: No, it return nothing. :)

Comment: Obviously it is in the link in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
$input = $_POST['oviliz'];
$replaces = array(
    'a' => '1',
    'b' => '2',
    'c' => '3',
    'd' => '4',
    'e' => '5',
);
$letters = str_split($input);
foreach($letters as $letter){
    $total += $replaces[$letter];
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>My input text: <input name="oviliz" type="text"/><input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
</form>
<?php
echo "Numbers: " . $input;
echo "= " . $total;
?>
```

Comment: The total is correct but as the first result is shows me letters instead numbers.